# Delphi 10 - Loading an array with TImages by name

Tags: delphi-2010

I have a 20 different Timages on the form named tile1, tile2, tile3 ... tile20.

tiles[] is just an array of Timage (1..20)

With the following code I am unsuccessfully loading each Timage into its respective index of the tiles[] array

```
procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
I : integer;
begin

for I := 1 to 20 do
begin
  tiles[I] := TImage( ( 'tile' + inttostr(I) ) );      
end;

end;
```

the code doesn't produce any warnings or fatal errors, the problem arises when I try to access the data of each TImage through the array

eg ShowMessage(tiles[1].name) should produce 'tile1', instead I get nothing

How can I achieve this without manually coding each Timage into the array

eg.

tiles[1] := tile1;

tiles[2] := tile2;

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 20 TImage components are actually on the form (since your example doesn't show it) you can use the `FindComponent` method of the form.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    tile1: TImage;
    tile2: TImage;
    tile3: TImage;
    // ...       (tiles 4 through 18 omitted to shorten the code sample)
    tile19: TImage;
    tile20: TImage;    
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

  private
    tiles : array[1..20] of TImage;

  public
  end;

   //...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

var
   i : integer;

begin
   for i := 1 to 20 do
      begin
         tiles[i] := TImage(FindComponent('tile'+inttostr(i)));
         if tiles[i] = nil then
            ShowMessage('tile'+inttostr(i)+' not found !');
      end
end;
```

---

"code doesn't produce any warnings or fatal errors,"

```
tiles[I] := TImage( ( 'tile' + inttostr(I) ) );
```

The code compiles fine because you are simply casting a string as a TImage.  As to not receiving any run-time messages, well, that is just pure amazing luck.

The code:

```
ShowMessage(tiles[1].Name);
```

should raise an access violation exception since `tiles[1]` points to a string and not to an instance of TImage.